# Top recent tags in profile

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Currently, in a Careers profile we have "Top 10% in Tag XY". This is nice, but I think it would be even better to display that value not for "All time", but only for the last 30 (or 60 or 90) days. I believe, the recent activity is even more interesting to others.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say I really understand where you're coming from. You certainly wouldn't say that about the employment or education sections of the profile so I don't know why it would apply here or what makes it more interesting.

Comment: I think it also is relevant for the employment and education sections. But there you are free to only fill in the recent activity. Really, no one cares what I have done 10 years ago, if I haven't done something similar lately.

Comment: @Daniel:  There are two orders of magnitude between 90 days and 10 years, I don't see how your 10 years argument could apply to something 90 days old.